# RemoteReader : Handle image generated by query parameter

Tags: iis, imageresizer

I have a use case where the RemoteReader plugin on our ImageResizer needs to handle the following url syntax:

> http://imageresizer.local/remote/somedomain.com/segment/documentviewer/get_image.hml?img_name=filename.jpg

Out of the box, it seems that RemoteReader just looks to get_image.html to be the image, and doesn't utilize the query param to lookup an actual image. I understand how it would be hard for the plugin to know which params to send along with the request in order to get an image response.

My question is, will I need to fork the plugin to get this functionality, or is there a way I can force the plugin to send the entire url with params? Maybe I can utilize IIS url rewrites to help with this.  Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem you are seeing is because IIS is set up to never "run" files named *.html.  Did you "install" imageresizer or just copied the files to the server?

Comment: I have an ImageResizer as a standalone IIS server, the imageresizing binaries were installed via NuGet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the same querystring both for the remote server and for imageresizer. That would confuse both.

You'll need to base64 encode the remote URL (including querystring) and use the less human-friendly syntax accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for this. What I did to ship it as fast as possible was intercept the RemoteUrl property from args (within Current_AllowRemoteRequest), and tack on the get_image query param to the args.RemoteUrl. Your solution sounds more robust, and I will revise my solution. Love your work by the way!
Edit: I'm not able to mark the answer as useful due to my (lack of) rep.